# Trying to use Steam API, but get Cross-Origin Request Blocked. Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http-get, steam

Using the steam API. I can access it fine in my browser and all of the json data shows.

Now, I am making a angular project. A website that'll have stats from steam's api for a game, which is in that json data ^

However, I am having a issue when I try using it.

**data.service.ts**

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
export class DataService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

GetUser() {
return this.http.get('https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=252490&key=IREMOVEDMYAPIKEYOBVIOUSLY&steamid=IALSOREMOVEDTHESTEAMID').subscribe(data=>{
  console.log(data)})
 }
}
```

**app-search.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';


export class AppSearchComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private data: DataService) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
this.data.GetUser();
 }
}
```

Looking in the console on inspect element it shows:

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at **APILINK** (it's long). (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200."

and then

ERROR
Object { headers: {…}, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "**APILINK**", ok: false, name "HttpErrorResponse", message: "HttpFailure response for **APILINK**: 0 Unknown Error", error: error }

if I use https://reqres.in/api/users for a test with getting a api, it seems to work.. but steam? CORS error. I figure someone here should know better than me what's wrong here..

as another note, currently it's ran as "ng serve" so it's localhost right now.

and, for steam's api you can revoke and generate a key again. It wants you to specify a domain though (is putting localhost not okay?)

[api key register image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Yvf9.png)

do note that I have gotten a api key, I just now revoked it. (you can generate them again easily) but perhaps that is worth looking at (the domain you must enter). I have deployed this to firebase and used that url of the firebase website.. same error on local and firebase website

Comment: I have no idea on how to fix this, it seems a little complex.. I'm just getting a CORS error trying to access steam's API. That's all it seems.. but I don't know a good way to fix it.

Comment: I have tried looking into express but I just get so lost with regards to calling steams api, most of the things I look at seem as if they call something local rather then a external api.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Angular, but I believe the code you're showing is running on the user's browser(?). For security reasons, a browser will not make cross-origin requests (requests from your website to Steam for example) unless the endpoint (Steam) specifically allows it. Steam does not allow it. Furthermore, your component code would be exposing your Steam API key to the users of your website which is a very bad thing. What you want to be doing is proxying the steam api call through your own backend server so that your web page can send a request to your own server (same origin).

Comment: Imagine your website has an endpoint like yourwebsite.com/GetUserStatsForGame which simply sends a request to api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame and returns the response. The important bit is that the request to steam is done on your own server's back end and not in the browser.